# why online document libraries is ignoring the "Open document in the browser settings"

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365

I have a document library inside our sharepoint online team site. Now inside the online document library i specify the following settings for the "Opening Documents in the browser" settings:-

[image]

but inside our document library, we have a PDF file + Excel sheet + Word document. and when i click on them they are going to open inside the browser and not inside the client application. as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone advice why online document libraries is ignoring the "Open document in the browser settings" 
Regards

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot this issue, check things below:

1. Ensure the Office is installed in the client.
2. Switch to other browser such as IE and check the result.

If you are using Chrome, the cause could be the Netscape Plugin API (NPAPI) support is disabled.

More information:

[Can't open SharePoint documents in a local client (rich client) from Chrome when NPAPI plug-in is missing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/3095447/can-t-open-sharepoint-documents-in-a-local-client-rich-client-from-chr)

[Fix problems opening documents in SharePoint libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-problems-opening-documents-in-SharePoint-libraries-31329fa1-4ad0-47fc-95d8-bb0c5b12a536).

Comment: now i tested this on firefox and chrome and the documents opened inside the browser ,, while using IE the document got opened inside the client application as mentioned inside the document library settings..

Comment: It is a browser issue as IE works. Check the browser, see if the Netscape Plugin API (NPAPI) plugin is disabled. refer to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/3095447/can-t-open-sharepoint-documents-in-a-local-client-rich-client-from-chr

Comment: but when we first created the sites (5 months ago), all the documents were opening with the client application under all browser vendors,, but recently this breaks , and users start to see that document are being opened inside the browsers when using non-IE browsers such as chrome,Firefox and Edge.. so i am pretty sure this is not an issue with the browser itself, but rather with the tenant itself.. also i tested this on another tenant and the settings for the "Opening Documents in the browser" is working as excepted, where documents will be opened inside the client applications

Comment: Check the version of Chrome and Firefox in these machines. the versions in non-working machine and working machine would be different.

Comment: now the case as follow, using a user machine i login to Firefox , click on a document it got opened inside the browser. now using the same user machine i login to another tenant, click on the document it got opened inside the client application... now the 2 tenants have the exact same settings for the document library, as shown in my original picture!! now if i using IE the document will always open inside the client application on the 2 tenants...

Comment: At the end of the first article you can read _"The fix for this issue has been rolled out as of August 11, 2015, and it should be in build 15.0.4745.1000 and later."_ So I assume a fix and/or alternative was develop on that version of Sharepoint.